# Perl - regexp not being replaced

Tags: regex, perl

I have an array containing words that I want to remove from each line of a file. The code I am using is as follows:

```
my $INFILE;
my $OUTFILE;
my $STOPLIST;
open($INFILE, '<', $ARGV[0]);
open($STOPLIST, '<', "stop.txt");
open($OUTFILE, '>', $ARGV[1]);

my @stoplist = <$STOPLIST>;

my $line;
my $stopword;
while (<$INFILE>) {
    $line = $_;
    $line =~ s/\[[0-9]*\] //g;
    $line =~ s/i\/.*\/; //g;
    foreach (@stoplist) {
        $stopword = $_;
        $line =~ s/${stopword}//g;
    }
    print $OUTFILE lc($line);
}
```

However, the words in the stoplist still appear in the text in the output file, which would indicate that the `$line =~ s/${stopword}//g;` line wasn't doing it's job as I expected.

How can I make sure that all words in the stop list that appear in the input text are replaced with 0 characters in the output?

Comment: You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings`. If you don't then you may as well not bother declaring your variables either.

Comment: `s/i\/.*\/; //g` will remove text from the *first* occurrence of `i/` to the *last* occurrence of `/; ` in the string, so if there is more than one occurrence of `i/.../;` then everything between them will also be deleted. If there is *never* more than one such string then you don't need the `/g` modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove newlines from your stoplist using [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
my @stoplist = <$STOPLIST>;
chomp @stoplist;
```